# ul in div don't work

Tags: html, css

Here is [jsfiddle.net/27wMk/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/27wMk/1/) code

> list-style-position: inside;

Don't work

I need some fix for tabs be into div. I'm very sorry for my bad english. Thanks

code html:

```html
<div class="reply">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
            <label for="tab1">Login</label>
            <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                First tab
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
            <label for="tab2">Reg</label>
            <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                Second tab
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a clearfix to the `<ul>` so it will contain its child elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/v48d9/

Reference: [Clearfix Methods](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Comment: Thanks, i will read link. But also, you didnt add anything to jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle link not working. please double check before you post answer

Comment: Updated link. It was working before. Don't know what happened. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` and add display style as `inline-table`

```
.tabs li{
    // float: left
    display: inline-table;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/27wMk/6/)**

Comment: `display: inline-table` is another method of the "clearfix" hack. Each one has tradeoffs.

http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/understanding-humble-clearfix

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset ul

```
ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;}
```

To clear default atributes from browser..

And you can add a float:left;